# Generating different passwords according to a string - Activation Key

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my program activated by a password on Java. Basically while user is registering, a "teacher pass" which are given by an authorized personal will be asked and if it's correct, program will allow the user to use itself.

Students can also use the program but they can't reach some of its content.

```
private static String encrypt()
{   
    String s = "CORNFLAKES";
    String pass = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int i = rnd.nextInt(s.length());
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        pass += ""+ i + s.charAt(i);
        i = rnd.nextInt(s.length());
    }
    return pass;
} 

private static boolean decrypt (String s)
{   
    if(s.length() != 14)
        return false;
    String teacherPass = "CORNFLAKES";
    String[] tokens = s.split("A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|Q|P|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z");
    int loc;
    for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++)
    {
        loc = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
        if(s.charAt(2*i+1) != teacherPass.charAt(loc))
            return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Definetly there is a better solution for it, but what it is? By the way, I use MySQL for keeping the user info.

Comment: Wait, you need to save the password encoded in some file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into hashing for storing your passwords and then hash it again on login and compare the hashes.

For instance:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Hashing (when properly used and implemented) has a very nice property for password storage and validation:
The procedure can't be reversed. So even if someone were to access your user credentials table, they would not learn anything about your users password. Checking the entered password against the stored hash happens by hashing the new input aswell and comparing the hashes.

Also you should never write things like this yourself if you are not a security expert because  you will invariably make a small mistake that makes the whole system insecure. Use suitable libraries.

You should also look into salts for your hashes, but start with simple hashes and move on once you understand the basics.

Comment: Also, Java provides SHA (and others) implementation using `MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");`